# CoreData rarely 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation.'

Tags: ios, core-data, crash

This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation.

> NSInternalInconsistencyException(SIGABRT)
>   This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation.

```
    0   CoreFoundation  0x000000018268a59c  ___exceptionPreprocess + 132
    1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000192dd40e4  objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreData    0x000000018240a658  ___65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 5080
    3   CoreData    0x0000000182411654  _gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 180
    4   libdispatch.dylib   0x000000019341936c  __dispatch_client_callout + 16
    5   libdispatch.dylib   0x00000001934226e8  __dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 76
    6   CoreData    0x0000000182404cb4  __perform + 180
    7   CoreData    0x0000000182342c34  -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 300
    8   CoreData    0x0000000182342c64  -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 348
    9   CoreData    0x0000000182369400  -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1284
    10  RBookReader 0x00000001000109d4  __44-[RCCoreDataManager mocDidSaveNotification:]_block_invoke (RCCoreDataManager.m:186)
    11  CoreData    0x00000001823dd270  _developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 200
    4   libdispatch.dylib   0x000000019341936c  __dispatch_client_callout + 16
    13  libdispatch.dylib   0x00000001934234c0  __dispatch_queue_drain + 1216
    14  libdispatch.dylib   0x000000019341c474  __dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
    15  libdispatch.dylib   0x0000000193425224  __dispatch_root_queue_drain + 664
    16  libdispatch.dylib   0x000000019342675c  __dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001935f52e4  _pthread_wqthread + 812
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001935f4fa8  __pthread_set_self + 12
```

this is my Code:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (!_persistentStoreCoordinator)
    {
        self.storeURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[XQDocumentPath() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model.sqlite"] isDirectory:NO];

        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                       nil];

        NSError *error = nil;
        _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
        @try {
            if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:self.storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
                if (error) {
                    DLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    DLog(@"rm \"%@\"", self.storeURL.path);
                }
            };
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            DLog(@"addPersistentSoreWithType fail, reason = %@",exception.description);
        }
        @finally {

        }
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


#pragma mark
#pragma mark -context save notification
- (void)mocDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)noti
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *savedContext = [noti object];

    // Ignore change notifications for the top MOC.
    if (!savedContext.parentContext) {
        return;
    }

    if (!savedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        return;
    }

    // Ignore changes for other databases.
    if (self.privateObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator != savedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        return;
    }

    [savedContext.parentContext performBlock: ^{
        NSError *error;
        if (savedContext.parentContext.hasChanges) {
            @try
            {
                if (![savedContext.parentContext save: &error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Error saving context %@: %@", savedContext.parentContext, [error localizedDescription]);
#if defined DEBUG && defined TEST
                    [self showValidationError:error];
#else
#endif
                }
            }
            @catch(NSException *exception)
            {
                DLog(@"Unable to perform save: %@", (id)[exception userInfo] ?: (id)[exception reason]);
            }
            @finally
            {
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the `@try/@catch` will never fire.  Core Data does not throw exceptions like that in Objective-C.

Second, it seems like your `addPersistentStoreWithType...` is failing but your `DLog` (assuming it is based on my `DLog`) is silent in production.

Therefore, I would suggest the following:

1. Remove the `@try/@catch` blocks, they don't do anything
2. Change your `DLog` calls to at least `ALog` calls if not flat out crashing the app instead with information about why the store refused to add.

Comment: With those DLog statements you will never see it.  You need to change those and wait for the error to occur again.